# How do you rename a file URL to a variable in VB script?

Tags: vbscript, excel, vba

I'm making a program in Microsoft Excel using a bunch of VB script macros.
One of my macros gets data "From Web" and retrieves the table to a sheet in excel.  When I say "From Web", I just copied and pasted the URL from an html file I have on my desktop.  The location of my program is going to change frequently, so I need to be able to have a cell in excel where I can specify this URL, which my macro will reference.

Here is my code below:

```
 Sub ImportSwipeDataWithTitlesBeta()
'
' ImportSwipeDataWithTitlesBeta Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+K
'
Sheets("Import Swipe Data").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("A3").Select
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;file:///C:/Users/Sean/Desktop/Attendance Program ADC/ACS%20OnSite%20SE%20Complete.htm", _
    Destination:=Range("$A$3:$C$3"))
    .Name = "ACS%20OnSite%20SE%20Complete_8"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Sheets("Resource Sheet").Select
Range("B2:C2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Import Swipe Data").Select
Range("A1:B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to `.Select` every range you use. These statements are generated by recording a macro but you can clean your code afterwards as described [here](http://www.yogeshguptaonline.com/2009/03/write-excel-macro-clean-or-tweak-excel.html).

Yet, to answer your question, you can store your URL in a var:

```
Dim myURL As String

myURL = "URL;" & Sheets("Import Swipe Data").Range("A1").Value
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= myURL, Destination:=Range("$A$3:$C$3"))
   (...)
End With
```

Regards,